# Byte array convert to string c#

Tags: c#, string, byte

I have a byte array;

```
bytes = {"0X50","0X04","0X00","0X0A"}
```

I want convert to string this array like this;

```
string a = "50-04-00-0A"
```

How can i fix it in c#?
Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? What exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: That's an array of four strings, not a byte array

Comment: I have a byte [] variable. My example;
byte[0] = "0X50", byte[1] = "0X04" ..
I want convert to string but as it seems above.

Comment: if you really have a byte array it would look like this: `byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 0X50, 0X04, 0X00, 0X0A };` and the `0x50` is simply a convention to write it as hexadecimal format. So it seems that you would like to convert it to a string keeping the hex format but get rid of the `0x` part. Am I correct?

Comment: If your  variable _bytes_ is declared as _byte[]_ then you cannot put strings in it as you have showed above. Please fix the initialization above and probably your question could be reopened

Comment: if my assumption is true, than there is an `ToString` overload that you can use to do this. You need to pass `"X"` as parameter to specify the hex format. Then this line here: `Console.WriteLine(string.Join("-", bytes.Select(x=> x.ToString("X"))));` would be your solution. And this is also where I stop to play the guessing game here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have array of bytes (not strings as in question) you can use hexadecimal [string format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) ("X" or "x"):

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 0x50, 0x04, 0x00, 0x0A};
var strings = bytes.Select(b => b.ToString("X"));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("-", strings)); // prints 50-4-0-A
```

Comment: To get the output required you should have "X2"